# Selecting point with maximum value for each polygon

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

I have a point layer with two fields named `"id"` and `"price"`, and a polygon layer with a field named `"code_zone"`.

I need to get, for each polygon, the `"id"` of the point that has the highest value of `"price"`, and this maximum value of the `"price"`.

This is the beginning of my code:

```
for feature in layer_point.getFeatures():

   point_price = feature.attribute('price')
   point_geom = feature.geometry()

   for feat in layer_polygon.getFeatures():

      polygon_codeZone = feat.attribute('code_zone')
      polygon_maxValue = feat.attribute('max_value')
      polygon_geom = feat.geometry()

      if polygon_geom.contains(point_geom):
             ...
```

I tried with `maximumValue()`, but I get only the maximum value of the whole point layer and not the maximum value per polygon. What I am doing wrong?

As soon as I get these maximum values, I could fill them in my polygon layer with `polygon_layer.changeAttributeValue()` in the `"max_value"` field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dpr = layer_polygon.dataProvider()
max_value_index = layer_polygon.fields().indexFromName('max_value')

for pol in layer_polygon.getFeatures():
    g = pol.geometry()
    req = QgsFeatureRequest(g.boundingBox()) # for performance
    prices = [p["price"] for p in layer_point.getFeatures(req) if g.contains(p.geometry())]
    dpr.changeAttributeValues({pol.id(): {max_value_index: max(prices)}})
```

[image]

Comment: A big thank you, it looks perfect. I will test that tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

The user of a SQL query is appropriate for your problem.

I created 2 tables: one with 2 polygons and another with 5 points.

[image]

Then I go to the database manager > Virtual layers > and open a SQL query window

I execute the following request :

```
--First part : For each polygon, the prices of all the points that are contained.
-- An identifier (fid) is generated for each polygon in descending order of price.

WITH all_price AS
 (SELECT row_number() over(partition by poly.id_poly  ORDER BY point.price DESC) as fid, 
 poly.id_poly, point.id, point.price
 FROM poly, point
 WHERE St_contains(poly.geometry,point.geometry)
 ORDER BY poly.id_poly, point.price)

 --When fid is equal to 1, it means that it is the highest price.
 SELECT all_price.id_poly, all_price.id, all_price.price
 FROM all_price 
 WHERE fid = 1
```

Result of the temporary table all_price on the left and the final result on the right. If you don't understand the request, I can give you more explanations.

[image]

Comment: Thank you man, I didn't try to use SQL to solve my problem.
Kadir's solution looks quicker to set up and run, but I'll still do some tests with SQL tomorrow to see what happens